# Jquery sortable horizontal list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am having a difficult time getting my jquery sortable lists to display horizontally.  The user is suppose to drag a report part onto stage, then drop a column onto the report part.  As additional columns are dropped, the div should expand horizontally.  But everything I try it always sorts vertically.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/asleepatmydesk/kNfGC/

When the report control is dropped onto the stage, i'm trying modify the css of the <ul> and the <li>like so:

```
    $('.stage').droppable({
        accept: '.reportControl',
        tolerance: "fit",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
            $('.stage .reportControl').replaceWith(gridControlDropped);

            $('.gridControlDropped')
                .draggable({
                handle: '.filterContainer',
                cursor: 'move',
                containment: '.stage'
            })
            var ul = $('.droppedColumns')
            ul.sortable({
                connectWith: ".connected",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"

            })


        }
    });
      var ul = $('.droppedColumns')   //modifying the ul
            ul.sortable({
            connectWith: ".connected"
            , placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"

      })
       .css({
            'float': 'left'
            , 'display':'inline-block'
           });

          var li = $('.droppedColumns li').css({
               'display': 'inline-block'
       });
```

But nothing seems to work.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to `gridControlDropped` class

```
.gridControlDropped {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think I haven't made my original problem clear.  I don't want the list on the left to become horizontal, I want the droppable/sortable list on the right to expand horizontally as columns are dropped on it.

Comment: I've gone back to the basics and started with two simple static sortable lists so that when the item on the left is dropped onto the list on the right, the list on the right expands horizontally.  I will build up to the dynamic functionality that I actually need and will post the solution when I figure it out.